# What does maximum resident set size mean?

Tags: linux, system-calls

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  struct rusage r_usage;
  while (++i <= 10) {
    void *m = malloc(20*1024*1024);
    memset(m,0,20*1024*1024);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&r_usage);
    printf("Memory usage = %ld\n",r_usage.ru_maxrss);
    sleep (3);
  }
  printf("\nAllocated memory, sleeping ten seconds after which we will check again...\n\n");
  sleep (10);
  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&r_usage);
  printf("Memory usage = %ld\n",r_usage.ru_maxrss);


  return 0;
}
```

The above code uses *ru_maxrss* attribute of *rusage* structure. It gives the value of maximum resident set size. What does it mean? Each time the program is executed it gives a different value. So please explain the output of this code?

[image]

[image]

These are screenshots of two executions of the same code which give different outputs, how can these numbers be explained or what can be interpreted from these two outputs?

Comment: in the meanwhile start digging with `man getrusage`

Comment: For starters, do you know what [resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) means?  "Maximum" means it's the largest that the RSS ever was during the process's life.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Resident set size (RSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) means, roughly, the total amount of physical memory assigned to a process at a given point in time.  It does not count pages that have been swapped out, or that are mapped from a file but not currently loaded into physical memory.

"Maximum RSS" means the maximum of the RSS since the process's birth, i.e. the largest it has ever been.  So this number tells you the largest amount of physical memory your process has ever been using at any one instant.

It can vary from one run to the next if, for instance, the OS decided to swap out different amounts of your program's memory at different times.  This decision would depend in part on what the rest of the system is doing, and where else physical memory is needed.

Comment: is it necessary that the physical memory assigned is always greater than the manual  memory assigned? in this example we are manually assigning 204800 kB in each iteration but the increase in physical memory allocated is different than this amount? will the physical memory be always greater?

Comment: can you please provide some context to numbers in the output to explain the maxrss in a better way.

Comment: @codeczar: Not necessarily.  To consider an extreme case, the OS could have swapped out each page of your allocation immediately after `memset` finished writing to it, and before you started writing the next one.  So the physical memory usage may increase only very slightly, or even not at all if the OS swaps out some other memory belonging to your process.

Comment: @codeczar: I don't know what you mean by "context".  The line `Memory usage = 42288` simply means that up to that point in time, the largest amount of physical memory that has been assigned to your process at any one time is 42288 kbytes.

Comment: I think I have already explained it the best way I know how.  I'm sorry if it's not helpful enough.