# Is there an equivalent for time([some command]) for checking peak memory usage of a bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, memory, command-line, ram

I want to figure out how much memory a specific command uses but I'm not sure how to check for the peak memory of the command.  **Is there anything like the `time([command])` usage but for memory?**

Basically, I'm going to have to run an interactive queue using `SLURM`, then test a command for a program I need to use for a single sample, see how much memory was used, then submit a bunch of jobs using that info.

Comment: `time([command])` that's odd syntax, it's never `time()`, after time there's a space `time command`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `time` is the **program** that monitors programs and shows the Maximum resident set size. Not to be confused with `time` Bash **builtin** that only shows real/user/sys times. On my Arch Linux you have to install `time` with  `pacman -S time`, it's a separate package.

```
$ command time -v echo 1
1
        Command being timed: "echo 1"
        User time (seconds): 0.00
        System time (seconds): 0.00
        Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1968
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 90
        Voluntary context switches: 1
        Involuntary context switches: 1
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 0
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0
```

Note:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
$ time -V
bash: -V: command not found

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
$ command time -V
time (GNU Time) 1.9
$ /bin/time -V
time (GNU Time) 1.9
$ /usr/bin/time -V
time (GNU Time) 1.9
```

Comment: For any **macOS** users, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207962/2836621

Comment: How do you check peak memory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779173/what-does-maximum-resident-set-size-mean